# run time error opening a new window by selecting a table content

Tags: qt, qtgui

I have the following slot from a push-button click that opens a new window.

```
void StageTwoPatients::on_pushButton_Open_clicked()
{
    QModelIndexList selection=ui->tableWidget->selectionModel()->selectedRows(0);

    this-> close();
    StageOneMain *newPatient = new StageOneMain(selection[0].data().toString(),this);
    newPatient-> show();
}
```

Here user needs to select a row from a table and click pushbutton to open a new window.

If the user dont select a row accidentally and click the push button I get runtime error as shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5owSA.jpg). How do I tell user using a `QMessageBox` that they should select a row before click push button?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried checking if there is a selection, and showing the messagebox if there is not? If yes, what problem did you encounter? If not, maybe try first, then update the code to show your non-working attempt.

Comment: You might also consider disabling the button until there is a selection, so you woudln't need a separate message box. Check the model or view docs on how to detect when selection changes, and update button enabled/disabled that way.

Comment: @hyde the second proposition make more sense ui wise.

Comment: "_How do I tell user using a QMessageBox that they should select a row before click push button?_" You simply implement what you suggested here. Have you tried that? But anyway, hyde has the superior idea IMO. Then you won't need to have another translatable string and think of wording for it. If the user can't do something yet, just don't let them. Ideally your UI will make it clear why they can't. If it doesn't, a tooltip on the disabled button might be better than a message box.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestions guys :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If the user dont select a row accidentally and click the push button I get runtime error

Simply do nothing if there is no selection.

```
void StageTwoPatients::on_pushButton_Open_clicked()
{
    QModelIndexList selection=ui->tableWidget->selectionModel()->selectedRows(0);
    if (selection.empty()){
        return;
    } 

    ...
}
```